# Style select options in Select2

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

The problem is how to apply a style on a part of an option.

I have a SELECT like this:

```
<select id="my_select">
   <option value="1">Item 1 <span class="color-red">20 calls</span></option>
   <option value="2">Item 2 <span class="color-red">10 calls</span></option>
   <option value="2">Item 3 <span class="color-red">30 calls</span></option>
</select>
```

Browsers don't allow tags within OPTION's and strip them.

So a possible workaround is using HTML entities:

```
<select id="my_select">
   <option value="1">Item 1 &lt;span class="color-red"&gt;20 calls&lt;/span&gt;</option>
   <option value="2">Item 2 &lt;span class="color-red"&gt;10 calls&lt;/span&gt;</option>
   <option value="2">Item 3 &lt;span class="color-red"&gt;30 calls&lt;/span&gt;</option>
</select>
```

Now a browser sees the entire content of each OPTION as a text. And here's the Jquery code:

```
$('#my_select').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1
});
```

The last thing I stumbled on is replacing the entities "&lt;" and "&gt;" with "<" and ">" symbols respectively AFTER the Select2 is rendered and on a dropdown, to get in the first option box "Item 1" in default black color and "20 calls" in red color (CSS is available: .color-red {color:red;}). And the same for the other option boxes.

I've tried to find the answer in the documentation, but nothing worked. For example,

```
$('#my_select').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    templateResult: function (item) {
    item.text.replace (/&gt;/g,'>').replace (/&lt;/g,'<');
    }
});
```

Any ideas on how to solve this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `templateResult` callback function needs to _return_ the option content. But there is also automatic HTML escaping applied, so you need to return a jQuery object instead of plain HTML, see https://select2.org/dropdown#built-in-escaping

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'd be happy to get any examples. Can you help please?

Comment: Something like `templateResult: function (item) { return $('<div>foo <span style="color:red">bar</span></div>'); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the `escapeMarkup` option to allow HTML content.

In `templateResult` you inform how and in what way you want to render the content, in this case I use the return of a data-text attribute in each option.

```js
$('#my_select').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
  escapeMarkup: function(item) {
    return item;
  },
  templateResult: function(item) {
    return $(item.element).data('text');
  }
});
```

```css
.color-red {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_select" style="width: 100%;">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1" data-text='Item 1 <span class="color-red">20 calls</span>'>Item 1 20 calls</option>
  <option value="2" data-text='Item 2 <span class="color-red">10 calls</span>'>Item 2 10 calls</option>
  <option value="3" data-text='Item 3 <span class="color-red">30 calls</span>'>Item 3 30 calls</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You've saved me weeks of time, I think. Thank you so much!